# Regarding transient fields

Tags: blackberry

I have a class which implements persistable and a transient boolean member in this class. I noticed that thought he variable is declared as transient its state is being persisted. How do i over come this issue. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blackberry's persistence mechanism does not respect `transient`. Possible solutions are:

- split the object into two parts, persistable and not, or
- use a different object format (perhaps something generic like a `Hashtable`) only for persistance, copying out into the "real" object after it is loaded and then writing back into the dummy object for saving.

(See [this forum thread](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Transient-keyword/td-p/555974))